# Symfony FOSUserBundle error

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

So, I've made an app with its own controller and entities. I've just installed the FOSUserBundle following the guide and I want to connect my app to the login, register, etc. I tried using the function 'path'. This is what looks like... `'href="{{path(menu.url)}}'` ok, so I get an error: 'such route does not exist'. I decided to create another controller, this one called `FosController`, next to my previous one the `DefaultController`, I extended the `FosController` from `SecurityController(login fosuserbundle)` and decided to create with annotation a route called login and connect it to the parent method...

```
class FosController extends SecurityController
{   

/**
 * @Route("/hospitallogin", name="login")
 * @Method({"GET", "POST"})
 *
 * @param Request $request
 *
 * @return Response
 */
public function login2Action(Request $request) {
    parent::loginAction($request);
}


}
```

And I get this error:

The controller must return a response (null given). Did you forget to add a return statement somewhere in your controller?

I dont know what else to do, thanks for your time.

Comment: Is there a faster way to connect my app to the login action ?

Answer (score 0):

I decided to use this though it's not correct...

```
public function indexAction()
{
    return $this->redirect('http://localhost:8000/login');
}
```